# How to pass $('#formvalues').serialize() together wirth an js array in ajax?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel

Is it possible submit a form data together with a javascript array in ajax? Here is my sample code:

```
shipmententry = JSON.stringify(trucksarray.concat(equipmentsarray)));
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/dashboard/importation-registration/shipment-registry/create',
    //data: {$('#form_shipment_registry').serialize(),shipmententry }
    data: shipmententry,
    dataType: 'json',
    encode: true
})
```

ps: `shipmententry` data will be stored in the same table, and `$('#form_shipment_registry').serialize()` data will be stored in a separate table.

but in my console.log() it returns as escaped string . I just want to pass this data to my laravel controller and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize into a json string and pass it along with the rest of the data from the form then decode it on the server.

```
shipmententry = JSON.stringify(trucksarray.concat(equipmentsarray)));
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/dashboard/importation-registration/shipment-registry/create',
    data: $('#form_shipment_registry').serialize() + '&shipmententry=' + encodeURIComponent(shipmententry),
    dataType: 'json'
});
```